# Dar color y quitar IP o Localhost a alerta - PHP

Tags: php, css, bootstrap, php8

tengo un sistema que al momento de querer eliminar un registro lo uso mediante el evento OnClick

y al momento de agregar un usuario lo uso mediante un Echo, la cosa es que quisiera saber si a esta alerta se le puede agregar algo de color y quitarle la IP que sale

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cosa es que no se como hacerlo, este es el codigo que se usa para agregar usuarios

```
<?php

include('../conexion.php');

//Agregar un nuevo usuario

if( isset($_POST['ingresar_usuario']) ){

  $id = $_POST['id'];
$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$id_tipo_usuario = $_POST['id_tipo_usuario'];
$porcentaje_participacion = $_POST['porcentaje_participacion'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id,id_usuario,clave, nombres, apellidos,email,id_tipo_usuario,porcentaje_participacion ) VALUES ('$id','$id_usuario','$clave', '$nombres', '$apellidos', '$email', '$id_tipo_usuario', '$porcentaje_participacion')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo   
'<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Usuario Agregado Exitosamente");
  window.location.href="usuarios.php";
  </script>';

}

?>
```

y este es el codigo que se uso para eliminar un usuario

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                        
                                            <a href=" eliminar_usuario.php?id= <?php echo $row['id']   ?> " onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?');">
                                                <i class="material-icons">Eliminar</i>
 </div>
```

Es algo basico pero pues estoy aprendiendo, agradeceria la ayuda

Comment: Esa instrucción `echo` que contiene el `alert` de JavaScript, puedes reemplazarla por cualquier código HTML, por ej. Si no quieres personalizar el diseño, podrías hacer uso de librerías como [SweetAlert2.js](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). Ahora, ya que estás usando Bootstrap, una forma sencilla sería con [un modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#how-it-works)

Comment: Los alert por defecto del navegador no pueden ser modificados, hay varios tipos de alert que puedes utilizar pero con formato predeterminado, lo único que puedes modificar es el mensaje, para eso utiliza librerías externas como te menciona @JheymanMejia en donde si puedes personalizarlos a tus necesidades.